# PHP MySQL single column/row display?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a single result from my database, just one name.
I tried using;

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = '$id'"));
echo $row['name'];
```

But that din't work, any other way to simply show only one result?
Thanks in advance!

[EDIT:]
*(I'm using PHP 5.3)*

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$id = $_GET['deletid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = '$id' LIMIT 1");
if(!$result){
    echo mysql_error();
}
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name'];
}
echo "<p>id:$id</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting LIMIT 1 on the end of your query?

Comment: @Harold I tried it but still didn't work.

Comment: @Jay Wit, hei man, listen to me: What are you trying to do in that page? What action are you attempting to do? I'm gonna write a code for you.

Comment: Is it just me or is it just possible that the table just doesn't have the id specified?! Where are you getting the id from. (And don't say from the query string.)

Comment: @Charlie I'm trying to display a single name from the database. I'm 'actually' trying to remove a file aswell, that why I need the name. The file name is the same name as in the database, it works perfect, but I just can't seem to get a single name this way.

Comment: @anothershrubery I'm getting it from the link with a GET, there is nothing wrong with the $id var, when I echo it, it show the right id.

Comment: So the problem is that the query result has too many rows?! (Impossible if you are using `LIMIT 1`) What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just the name and you need just one result you should rewrite your query as follow:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM persons WHERE id = '". (int) $id ."' LIMIT 1"));
```

Now to get the result you should just get it with a

```
$row['name'];
```

**EDIT**
Now that you posted your entire code i got what's wrong: You are deleting that result before getting its name. Basically you delete that user and then you attempt to get its name.
**EDIT**

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
    if (empty($_GET['deleteid'])) { 
        exit('"deleteid" is empty'); 
    }
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['deletid']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM persons WHERE id = '". (int) $id ."' LIMIT 1");
    if(!$result){
        echo mysql_error();
    }
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // for just one result you don't need of any loop
echo $row['name'];

echo "<p>id:". htmlspecialchars($id) ."</p>";
?>
```

Comment: No the $quer DELETE function isn't executed, I just placed it in a variable for later use.

Comment: @Jay Wit, no, using the function mysql_query the query is executed. To store the query for later use you should put something like `$var = "SELECT name FROM persons";` without the `mysql_query()` function.

Comment: I don't know what the difference was between the actual execution in your code and mine, but yours works perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM persons WHERE id = ". (int) $id));

echo $row['name'];
```

Comment: you need to either remove `."` or add `"` at the end of query.